# ID-number descriptive lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, scripts

I want to describe each part of an ID-number, like so:
[image: Descriptive lines]

How would I go about this? Could i set up something using tikz? I want to be able to describe IDs of different length and complexity. Preferably some script like feature. I'm not new to latex or tikz, but my usage have always been pretty straight forward.

Thank you!

Edit: After revisiting this old issue of mine, I've finally come up with a solution, that I'm quite happy with. So just in case someone stumbles on this, with a similar question I'll post it below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}
\begin{document}

\def\myhbar{1mm}
\def\myvbar{.3mm}
\def\myyshift{0mm}
\def\myxshift{0mm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myinnersep}{0.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=.5mm,font=\tiny\ttfamily, minimum height={height("Ag")+\myinnersep*1mm},inner sep=\myinnersep*1mm]
    \node [] (a1) at(2,0) {-rw-r--r--};
    \foreach [count=\x from 2] \txt in {\phantom{0}6,michael,admins,4096,Apr 25 13:53,some\_file.txt}{
        \pgfmathparse{\x-1}
        \node [right = of a\pgfmathresult] (a\x) {\txt};
    }
    \node [below = -1mm of a1] (b1) {drwxr-xr-x};
    \draw [] ([yshift=\myhbar+\myyshift,xshift=\myvbar]b1.south west) -- ([yshift=\myyshift,xshift=\myvbar]b1.south west) -- ([yshift=\myyshift,xshift=-\myvbar]b1.south east) -- ([yshift=\myhbar+\myyshift,xshift=-\myvbar]b1.south east);
    \foreach [count=\x from 2] \txt in {22,collins,editor,4096,Apr 25 13:53,some\_folder}{
        \pgfmathparse{\x-1}
        \node [right = of b\pgfmathresult] (b\x) {\txt};
        \draw [] ([yshift=\myhbar+\myyshift,xshift=\myvbar]b\x.south west) -- ([yshift=\myyshift,xshift=\myvbar]b\x.south west) -- ([yshift=\myyshift,xshift=-\myvbar]b\x.south east) -- ([yshift=\myhbar+\myyshift,xshift=-\myvbar]b\x.south east);
    }
    \foreach [count=\y from 1] \desc in {file permissions, number of links, user, group, size, date and time, name}{
        \node [anchor=west](c\y) at (0,-\y*2mm-5mm){\desc};
        \draw [<-,arrows={-[}] (c\y.east) -| ([yshift=\myyshift]b\y.south);
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi! Thank you.
Well I have to admit that scripting wise I haven't tried that much. I have done it to some succes with tikz alone, but it is not really replicable or scalable in an easy way, with changing length of the ID.

Comment: Old question, but it would be much better if you actually showed us what you have, then we don't have to start from scratch, or make any assumptions about your setup.